# What accessibility event is triggered when a notification is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, accessibilityservice, accessibility

So I have created a chat locking application for Whatsapp such that when user clicks on the locked contact, he/she cannot access the chat without the password or fingerprint. But on clicking the notification of that particular contact's chat, they can access the chat. So to block it, I need to know the accessibility events that get triggered on clicking the notification. I tried getting the events using AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK , but none of those events have a source and and I cannot get the nodes. Do anyone know any approach to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior may differ on different Android versions.

But when I tried clicking on a notification in the notification tray on a Galaxy S7 running Android 7.0 I got either `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` or `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED`, with package name `"com.android.systemui"`. And if I dumped the view hierarchy starting at the event source I got a `FrameLayout` containing 3 `TextView`s.